# Get styles of drag and dropped kml file in ol3

Tags: openlayers-3

Fooling around with ol3 to create some custom maps.

I drag and drop a KML file exported from Google Mymaps and that works great.  I want to get the styles that came with it so I can change them like stroke color for example.

I see using `feature.getKeys` that there is a key called styleUrl and using `feature.get('styleUrl')` I see that its value is **#style5**.

How can I get the stroke color from that style?

I have poked at everything I can think of with Chrome console but to no avail.

Comment: Try a `console.log` or `console.dir` on the object of interest.

Answer (score 0):

The actual style is saved in an object of the KML format, and accessed as a closure by the style function it sets on the features. This means that the styles themselves are inaccessible.

However, you could still access and manipulate the style values. The feature's getStyle method will either return a style, an array of styles or a style function. In this case, the KML formats sets a style function.

This function is called with a given resolution and return an array of styles. If you know for sure that the styles are static and not dependant on the resolution, you can just call the style function with an arbitraty resolution to obtain the style(s).

However, if you do not know for sure how the style function determines the return values, you could create an intermediate style function:

```
var oldStyleFunction = feature.getStyle();
feature.setStyle(function(resolution){
    var styles = oldStyleFunction.apply(this, arguments);
    for(var i = 0; i < styles.length; i++){
        var stroke = styles[i].getStroke();
        if (stroke != null) {
            console.log('style ' + i + ' stroke color: ' + stroke.getColor() + ' at resolution ' + resolution)
        }
    }
    return styles;
});
```

The example code above does not manipulate the style, but it is a good starting and will show you the styles stroke color.